# Efficient and scalable storage for JSON data with NoSQL databases

Tags: json, mongodb, hadoop, couchdb, cassandra

We are working on a project which should collect journal and audit data and store it in a datastore for archive purposes and some views. We are not quite sure which datastore would work for us.

- we need to store small JSON documents, about 150 bytes, e.g. `"audit:{timestamp: '86346512',host':'foo',username:'bar',task:'foo',result:0}"` or `"journal:{timestamp:'86346512',host':'foo',terminalid:1,type='bar',rc=0}"`
- we are expecting about one million entries per day, about 150 MB data
- data will be stored and read but never modified
- data should stored in an efficient way, e.g. binary format used by Apache Avro
- after a retention time data may be deleted
- custom queries, such as `'get audit for user and time period'` or `'get journal for terminalid and time period'`
- replicated data base for failsafe
- scalable

Currently we are evaluating NoSQL databases like Hadoop/Hbase, CouchDB, MongoDB and Cassandra. Are these databases the right datastore for us? Which of them would fit best?
Are there better options?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- One million inserts / day is about 10 inserts / second.  Most databases can deal with this, and its well below the max insertion rate we get from Cassandra on reasonable hardware (50k inserts / sec)
- Your requirement "after a retention time data may be deleted" fits Cassandra's column TTLs nicely - when you insert data you can specify how long to keep it for, then background merge processes will drop that data when it reaches that timeout.
- "data should stored in an efficient way, e.g. binary format used by Apache Avro" - Cassandra (like many other NOSQL stores) treats values as opaque byte sequences, so you can encode you values how ever you like.  You could also consider decomposing the value into a series of columns, which would allow you to do more complicated queries.
- custom queries, such as 'get audit for user and time period' - in Cassandra, you would model this by having the row key to be the user id and the column key being the time of the event (most likely a timeuuid).  You would then use a get_slice call (or even better CQL) to satisfy this query
- or 'get journal for terminalid and time period' - as above, have the row key be terminalid and column key be timestamp.  One thing to note is that in Cassandra (like many join-less stores), it is typical to insert the data more than once (in different arrangements) to optimise for different queries.
- Cassandra has a very sophisticate replication model, where you can specify different consistency levels per operation.  Cassandra is also very scalable system with no single point of failure or bottleneck.  This is really the main difference between Cassandra and things like MongoDB or HBase (not that I want to start a flame!)

Having said all of this, your requirements could easily be satisfied by a more traditional database and simple master-slave replication, nothing here is too onerous

Comment: I've forgot to mention that the json data my vary, fixed and variable fields. A RDBMS requires a fixed schema. So searching would lead to fulltext search and thats always expensive. What we need is a flexible storage with reasonable indexes.

Comment: HBase works well with sparse columns, meaning you can add new columns (not Column Families) at any time, and any given row does not require a value for all columns. However, the design is such that it is not as easy (although still possible) to query in the same way as a traditional RDBMS. Sometimes not as quick, but after a certain point an RDBMS will fall over and HBase will just keep running with a predictable reporting time, once you establish how long it takes for X amount of data.

Answer (score 4):

Avro supports schema evolution and is a good fit for this kind of problem.

If your system does not require low latency data loads, consider receiving the data to files in a reliable file system rather than loading directly into a live database system.  Keeping a reliable file system (such as HDFS) running is simpler and less likely to have outages than a live database system.  Also, separating the responsibilities ensures that your query traffic won't ever impact the data collection system.

If you will only have a handful of queries to run, you could leave the files in their native format and write custom map reduces to generate the reports you need.  If you want a higher level interface, consider running Hive over the native data files.  Hive will let you run arbitrary friendly SQL-like queries over your raw data files.  Or, since you only have 150MB/day, you could just batch load it into MySQL readonly compressed tables.

If for some reason you need the complexity of an interactive system, HBase or Cassandra or might be good fits, but beware that you'll spend a significant amount of time playing "DBA", and 150MB/day is so little data that you probably don't need the complexity.

Answer (score 2):

We're using Hadoop/HBase, and I've looked at Cassandra, and they generally use the row key as the means to retrieve data the fastest, although of course (in HBase at least) you can still have it apply filters on the column data, or do it client side. For example, in HBase, you can say "give me all rows starting from key1 up to, but not including, key2".

So if you design your keys properly, you could get everything for 1 user, or 1 host, or 1 user on 1 host, or things like that. But, it takes a properly designed key. If most of your queries need to be run with a timestamp, you could include that as part of the key, for example.

How often do you need to query the data/write the data? If you expect to run your reports and it's fine if it takes 10, 15, or more minutes (potentially), but you do a lot of small writes, then HBase w/Hadoop doing MapReduce (or using Hive or Pig as higher level query languages) would work very well.

Comment: Data will be written permanently, the load depends on whether a service will be executed. The queries will be executed ad-hoc on user interaction. Queries must be excuted in a reasonable time duration. So Map-Reduce won't be feasible right?

Comment: Well, what is a reasonable time duration for you? The time execution take will partly be based on the amount of data (number of records), and part on the size of your Hadoop cluster. For example, on our 6 node cluster, it takes something like 5-7 minutes for 6M or so records, but each record has a lot of data associated with it. That's straight MapReduce off of HDFS, not MapReduce off of HBase which can be just as fast or faster depending on the Scan.

Answer (score 1):

If your JSON data has variable fields, then a schema-less model like Cassandra could suit your needs very well.  I'd expand the data into columns rather then storing it in binary format, that will make it easier to query.  With the given rate of data, it would take you 20 years to fill a 1 TB disk, so I wouldn't worry about compression.

For the example you gave, you could create two column families, Audit and Journal.  The row keys would be TimeUUIDs (i.e. timestamp + MAC address to turn them into unique keys).  Then the audit row you gave would have four columns, `host:'foo'`, `username:'bar'`, `task:'foo'`, and `result:0`.  Other rows could have different columns.

A range scan over the row keys would allow you to query efficiently over time periods (assuming you use ByteOrderedPartitioner).  You could then use secondary indexes to query on users and terminals.